# VFP Modify report - Limitations

Tags: report, visual-foxpro

I have an application which uses the MODIFY REPORT command so that the user can make changes to items such as labels so that he can tailor the report to his own requirements.

On my Win7 machine this works fine, both when run within a VFP session and when I run the application as a free-standing .exe.

On my Win10 machine, this works fine under VFP, but the full properties window was not being displayed unless I include ReportBuilder.app in the folder with my .exe program ((I also see that I have to include several .dll files (vfp9r.dll &c) in order for the .exe to run.

Is this the correct approach to follow, or is there another way of doing this (even binding some of this code into the .exe file).  Grateful for guidance  - or being pointed in the direction of some relevant documentation - as ever.  Andrew M.

Answer (score 1):

Either in win 10 or an older version of windows, Modify Report works just fine and doesn't need the inclusion of reportbuilder.app. Including runtime files is a must though (vfp9*.dll). If you make calls to reportbuilder.app (I don't for example) then you need to provide it.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case.  The application does not make any direct call to Report Builder.app. 

(On the W10 machine) If ReportBuilder.app is present, MODIFY REPORT works fine, showing all the tabs of Field Properties when you right-click on a field in the report layout.

If ReportBuilder.app is renamed or removed, then MODIFY REPORT reverts to showing the limited field properties “Report Expression”.

Other files present are vfp9r.dll, vfp8renu.dll, msvcr.dll, gdiplus.dll

Comment: Actually you are confirming that it is the case "... then MODIFY REPORT reverts to showing the limited field properties ...". IOW you are saying it works without reportBuilder.app. FWIW I am also using Modify Report in my projects and I have never included reportBuilder.app (and my applications are in use in many different platforms including windows 10).

Comment: You have said : “Modify report …doesn’t need the inclusion of reportbuilder.app”. I am saying this is _not_  always the case.  On the machine in question (my W10 machine), if ReportBuilder.app is not present, only limited field properties are available during MODIFY REPORT.  Does anyone else know why this might be happening?  Thanks.

Comment: I see we have a language problem :) ReportBuilder.app is an application that is added later and enhances that dialog. That 'limited' dialog is Modify Report's default dialog. If you ? _REPORTBUILDER in command window you would see reportBuilder.app is displayed. You can use your own app if you want to or include it in your project. In either case it is a matter of VFP finding the reportBuilder.app or not (not a matter of windows version).